# Using Django, how do I add a foreign key column that references the same table?

Tags: python, django, database

I want a table to include a foriegn key field to itself, and have tried the following code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CollectionModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(CollectionModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This produces the following error:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations eav
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/home/username/Documents/devel/python/project/eav/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class CollectionModel(models.Model):
File "/home/username/Documents/devel/python/project/eav/models.py", line 8, in CollectionModel
    parent = models.ForeignKey(CollectionModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'CollectionModel' is not defined
```

How do I include a foriegn key to the same table as a field?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey:

> To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use **models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)**.

The above code should be changed to:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CollectionModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below line to your model's

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

So, your model looks like,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CollectionModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```